# How to get Conference Sid at the time of dialing twilio call

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I've been working with twilio, using Node.js, and dialing call between two web end points. One is client and other is agent. I'm using following code to dial call.

```
    function dialCall(calledNumber, url) {

    client.calls.create({
        to: `client:${calledNumber}`,
        from: twilioNumber,
        url: url
      })
      .then(call => call.sid));
}
```

I'm using following twiml to establish a call.

```
 const generateTwiml = (conferenceName) => {
      let twimlResponse = new VoiceResponse();
  twimlResponse.say(`Welcome to unity dialer.`, {
    voice: 'alice',
  });
  const dial = twimlResponse.dial({
    timeLimit: '600',
  });
  dial.conference({
  startConferenceOnEnter: true,
  endConferenceOnExit: true
}, "Test Room");
  return twimlResponse.toString();
};
```

I've been successfully calling both agents and clients and getting callSid of both calls. However, my question is that at this point of time I also want to get conference Sid as well as I'm dialing the call as conference. What is the method to get that. As per documentation there is a method to fetch conference using conference name and status. However, if I use this some time the same is not returned due to race condition and I have to implement set time out function for same arbitrary delay. I've been getting the result but is there any other solution available for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At the time you return the TwiML to create the conference there is not yet a conference resource so there's no way to get the conference SID at that stage.

As you describe, you can use the conference resource to [list conferences and filter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference?code-sample=code-read-list-all-conferences&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x) by the name you give it. However, you can't list the conferences at the time you return the TwiML because that conference hasn't been created by then.

Rather than setting a timeout, which could be flaky, I recommend you use the [`statusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallback) of the `<Conference>` TwiML to set a URL to callback to when the conference starts. In the parameters to that callback you will get the `ConferenceSid`.